# SQL Combine same bind variable

Tags: sql, where-clause, clause

I have a where clause that says:

```
select * from tablename 
where :x < y or y is null 
and :x > z
```

I tried to rewrite it so that it uses :x once as shown below but I don't understand why I keep getting an error that says 'SQL command not properly ended'.

```
where z < :x < y or y is null
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you are trying to use `z < x < y` is not standard SQL.

You can come close with:

```
where :x between y and z or y is null;
```

The difference is that `between` is really `'y <= x <= z'`.  If inequality is really needed and the values are integers, you can easily do:

```
where :x between y + 1 and z - 1 or y is null;
```

Comment: Thank you, 
It was between I was looking for.